# Drupal Submenu on left sidebar

Tags: views, theming

I have added primary links and enable as expaned . Which is working fine for me

```
> About 
>  - test1 
>  - test2 
>  - test3
```

Now i want when i click on about or nay test1, test2, test3 page

I want a block on left sidebar containing  sub menu items

```
test1 
test2 
test3
```

Anybody have an idea how to do this

I am using Bootstrap 3 sub theme

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Menu Block Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block). It will display your menu as a block.

1) Create a new menu block.

2) Select parent menu as a "About".

3) Select its region and page visibility to about page url (and inner pages urls too if you want to display it on inner pages.)

4)Click on save.

Comment: Thansks a lot..